# What does this mean in python? counts = {x: y for x, y in counts.items() if x in self.symbols}

Tags: python, counter

This is from [this](https://github.com/kartikeya-shandilya/autogram/blob/master/autogram.py) source code I am trying to understand.

`counts = {x: y for x, y in counts.items() if x in self.symbols}`

I am new to python and am trying to convert this whole application to .NET. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Take a look at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get used to the syntax and the idea behind it

Comment: It's dot net equivalent could be: `counts.Where(kvp=>this.symbols.Contains(kvp.Key)).ToDictionary(kvp=>kvp.Key, kvp=>kvp.Value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet filters a dictionary by key.

```
{x: y   # create a key value pair from key and value (this basically copies the entry of counts
for x, y in counts.items()    # this iterates over all key value pairs in the counts dict (x is the key, y is the value)
if x in self.symbols   # only perform line 1 if they current key x is included in the list 'symbols'.
```

in C# this would look like:

```
counts = counts.Where(kv => symbols.Contains(kv.Key))  // this is the filter (line 3 from above)
               .ToDictinoary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);  // this creates the dict (line 1 from above)
```

Answer (score 0):

From a high-level perspective, the one-liner you provided updates a dictionary  instance (i.e. `counts`) and removes the elements that are not in `self.symbols`, effectively filtering `counts`.

Basically there is a dictionary `counts`, and what is being done is that each key-value pair `(x, y)` in `counts` is checked and a new dictionary instance that only includes the key-value pairs for which the key `x` exists in `self.symbols` is created. Finally, that newly created dictionary instance is assigned to `counts`. The formal name of this technique is **dictionary comprehension**.

The following code, which may seem more familiar to you, is equivalent to what you have given in your question.

```
filtered_counts = {}
for x, y in counts.items():
    if x in self.symbols:
        filtered_counts[x] = y
counts = filtered_counts
```

Answer (score 0):

## `dict` comprehension

It's a comprehension that returns a `dict`. Essentially, it iterates a pair of values through `counts.items()` and then creates a `dict` (key -> value mapping) out of it.

Let's say `counts.items()` is `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`. Then, `for x, y in counts.items()` will iterate with the following:

```
x = 1, y = 2
x = 3, y = 4
x = 5, y = 6
```

`if x in self.symbols` filters the comprehension. So if `self.symbols` were, say, `[1, 4, 5]`, it would only iterate through `x = 1, y = 2` and `x = 5, y = 6`.

Then, the final dict is:

```
{
    1: 2,
    5: 6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is dictionary comprehension. Some five lines of code can be written in a short form like this

```
counts = {x: y for x, y in counts.items() if x in self.symbols}
```